# Missing Log Tables Error

Tags: logs, logging, db-logging

It seems that daily, my System Status page is giving me the following error:

```
Missing Log Tables
You don't have logging enabled on some tables. This may cause errors on performing insert/update operation on them.
```

I then create the log tables, error goes away - next day - repeat.

Two activities I did in past couple weeks might have triggered this

1. Upgraded PHP version from 7 to 7.1 - while I believe I selected all the proper modules/extensions - there may have been something I missed.
2. Updated from 5.3.1 to 5.6

Wordpress

Comment: have just noticed same on one of our sites. will get one of team to dig and see what factors are causing it to show multiple times

Comment: At least its just not me - :)

Comment: just checked a day or so after using the 'create' option for the second time and doesn't seem to be showing again

Comment: Unfortunately - still ongoing for me.

Comment: Has also happened to me on a Drupal site, with PHP 7.1.22, with Civi at 5.6

Comment: I wonder if this is a 5.6 issue - @AndyClark did this start when you upgraded to 5.6?

Comment: I'm seeing this periodically, too, in conjunction with MyISAM warnings on a temporary table: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26969/temporary-table-keeps-showing-up-and-throwing-myisam-error

Comment: No it also happened sometimes with 5..1.2 but not before that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most people who have this issue are on CiviCRM 5.3-5.6, and is caused by the "missing logging tables" check assuming that temp tables should have a logging table.  [There is a fix available](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12984) on Github, and it's part of CiviCRM 5.7+.

Answer (score 2):

Here is summary of our situation after ours reappeared.

This was actually a wrong message shown on the status page. The logging is disabled on /civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1.

The flow which can lead to this error is -

- Logging is enabled on the site which generates a list of log tables in the database.
- User now disables the logging functionality on the site which now stops generating any more log tables.
- User create a custom set on the site which creates a new table in the database.
- The system status page notices a missing log table for the above and displays a warning.

The last step should also check if the logging is enabled on the site even if it is able to find some core log tables already present in the db.

Will submit a PR for this tomorrow.

Comment: This fits what happened to my site with this problem. I disabled logging because it caused a hang, then ended up with the above error. Good thinking Pete!

Comment: The PR submitted to fix this usecase is https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13010

Answer (score 1):

Cleared Litespeed Cache (a Wordpress cache) and error persisted.
Cleared CiviCRM Cache - error disappeared - but returned the next day. Same result as clicking rebuild tables. So the issue persists.

Comment: if you 'accept' your own answer (when you can) it kind of closes this off

Comment: Turns out I was premature.