# Temporary table keeps showing up and throwing MYISAM error and Missing Log Tables error

Tags: mysql, system-status

One installation I help with keeps throwing a MYISAM error that is related to a temporary table, as well as a "Missing Log Tables" error (which I assume is related as they always appear together). If I clear caches, the table disappears and the errors in the system status go away, but they comes back later.

Based on some grepping, it seems this is a "durable" temporary table, generated in `civicrm/CRM/Utils/SQL/TempTable.php` -- is there some way in this file that should be specifying INNODB? Or is there a configuration setting on my server/database that isn't set right?

Table name: `civicrm_tmp_d_dflt_randomstringofnumbersandlettershere`

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. "Your database is configured to use the MyISAM database engine. CiviCRM requires InnoDB. You will need to convert any MyISAM tables in your database to InnoDB. Using MyISAM tables will result in data integrity issues." Example Table Name: `civicrm_tmp_d_dflt_10ff2cc4b9e8b982843a5ac5673eda2c` Created when I export a .cvs file from a search. System Status::Clean up Caches makes the tables and the error go away. Drupal 7.60
CiviCRM 5.60
PHP 7.2.10 MySQL DB 5.5.5-10.2.18-MariaDB

Comment: unlikely but does it relate to this recent ticket about tmp table problems? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26960/missing-log-tables-error/27049?noredirect=1#comment30877_27049

Comment: @petednz-fuzion The missing log tables portion may be -- testing the patch from that ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a server tech look at this and it looks like this installation is on a server that has been upgraded from some time back, but retained an old setting:

> It looks like the default engine set within /etc/my.cnf was still set to MyISAM...

We are in process of updating that and will restart MySQL in the middle of the night soon. I'm assuming this will fix it (but will update here if not).